# What is the best way to manage an index for exact search and normal search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, normalize

I have a use case where I need normal match_all search i.e it shows me related documents with fuzzy results also, however I need a specific search which needs to do a term query.
My mappings are mostly string type:

```
"project_title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "projectabstract": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
"task_number": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      }
```

I did try exact search using lowercase normalizer by making task_number a keyword, but found out that I cant do a fuzzy search because it is a keyword. Since lowercase normalizer works only on keywords, if I convert the fields to keyword I cannot get search results I get from type: string. Should I maintain two indexes one with strings and another of type keyword or is there a better alternative to it ?

Comment: Lowercase is not only for keywords, the `standard` analyzer that is used by default on `text` fields, will lowercase the token during the analysis process. So your `task_number` field could also be both a text and a keyword

Comment: I came across two articles which say they are strictly about keywords. https://www.codementor.io/@mehuljain/case-insensitive-exact-matches-in-elasticsearch-nny7ii7fw

Comment: @Val if I add the normalizer to text type how should I use term search for exact search and match_all for normal search ?

Comment: Not really: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/analysis-standard-analyzer.html

Comment: Anything is possible, so you should show some sample queries you want to make and what results you expect, it's easier that way. Otherwise we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: @Val Here's a js fiddle (its js fiddle but query is normal dsl way.) https://jsfiddle.net/1ym2u7pz/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242530/discussion-between-leo-baby-jacob-and-val).